# How to rollback all transactions when writing multiple data frames to different SQL databases?

Tags: python, pandas, database, sqlalchemy, transactions

I am trying to write multiple data frames to different SQL databases, but if any of the tables fail then I would like to rollback all transactions. I know that when using a context manager, pandas takes care of the rollback if anything fails:

```
dfs = {
    "table1": pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3]}),
    "table2": pd.DataFrame({"A": [3,2,1]})
}

with engine.begin() as conn:
    for table_name, df in dis.items():
        df.to_sql(table_name, conn, index=False, if_exists="append)
```

... BUT this limits me to using the same connector for both tables - I need to use different connectors as I want to write these dataframes to different databases.

I have also tried "saving" the transactions to lists so that I can manually call rollback() afterwards:

```
trans = []
conns = []
engines = [engine1, engine2]
failed = False
for engine in engines:
    with engine.connect() as conn:
        try:
            tran = engine.begin()
            dfs["table1"].to_sql("table1", conn, index=False, if_exists="append")
            trans.append(tran)
            conns.append(conn)
        except:
            failed = True

if failed:
    for tran in trans:
        tran.rollback()
```

... BUT this doesn't work because once I've exited the context manager, the transactions are desassociated from the connection (I get the following warning):

`SAWarning: transaction already deassociated from connection tran.rollback()`

Any help would be really appreciated on this. If anything isn't clear in the question than please leave a comment and I will try to clarify. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using a context manager is recommended, but not absolutely required:

```py
acc_engine = sa.create_engine(
    sa.engine.URL.create(
        "access+pyodbc", query={"odbc_connect": connection_string}
    ),
)
sql_engine = sa.create_engine(
    "mssql+pyodbc://scott:tiger^5HHH@mssql_199",
)

# …

txn_list = []
failed = False
for engine in [sql_engine, acc_engine]:
    conn = engine.connect()
    txn_list.append(conn.begin())
    try:
        df.to_sql("so73211835", conn, if_exists="append", index=False)
    except sa.exc.IntegrityError:
        failed = True
        break

for txn in txn_list:
    if failed:
        print(f"rollback: {txn}")
        txn.rollback()
    else:
        print(f"commit: {txn}")
        txn.commit()
    txn.connection.close()
```